# Server not connect to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble connecting my server to MongoDb database using mongoose. The server will start and then crash while trying to connect to mongoDB. the error is getting caught in db.js and then exiting the program. It seems the server will connect to local host then end when it trys to connect to mongoDB.

ERROR!

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is running on : http://localhost:8000
MongoDB is not connected

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here Is my db.js I have linked it to my sever.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const connectDB = async()=>{
    try{
        await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://jj-test:jj@videos.cdstjfw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        console.log("MongoDB is connected!")
    }catch(err){
      console.log("MongoDB is not connected")
      console.error()
        process.exit(1)
    }
}   

module.exports=connectDB
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const crypto = require('crypto') 
const path = require('path')
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')
const multer = require('multer')
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream')

const connectDB= require('./services/db')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();

const init = async ()=>{

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cors());

await connectDB()

const conn = mongoose.connection


const gfs = await Grid(conn.db,mongoose.mongo)


gfs.collection('media')


// storage location using muster
const storage =  await  new GridFsStorage({
  db: conn.db,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename =
          buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename,
          bucketName: 'media'
        };
        return resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// uploading a file route
app.post('/upload',upload.single('file'),(req,res)=>{

 res.json(req.file)
})

// media bucket route

app.get('/files',async(req,res)=>{
try{
  const files =await gfs.files.find().toArray()

  res.json(files)

}catch(err){
  res.status(400).send(err)
}
 
  
})
// route for streaming a file
app.get('/read/:filename',async(req,res)=>{

  const{filename}= req.params
  try{
    const readstream = await gfs.createReadStream({filename})

    readstream.pipe(res)
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }

})
app.delete('/delete/:filename',async(req,res)=>{
  const{filename}=req.params
  try{
  
  await gfs.files.remove({filename})
   
    res.status(200).end()
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
})

}
init()

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on : http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add database name:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://jj-test:jj@videos.cdstjfw.mongodb.net/DATABASEname?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

Comment: I added still not working. and getting bad auth ass error

Answer (score 0):

Also worthwhile adding console.log(err) to help give more descriptive error info on the server.js file

Comment: I added my database_name and it still didn't connect also added console.log(err): this is the new error    "Server is running on : http://localhost:8000
MongoDB is not connected
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed."

Comment: This is the syntax: "mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...')" and I can see you're using "mongodb+srv://jj-test:jj@videos.cdstjfw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority" . I would propose this instead... "mongodb://jj-test:jj@localhost:8000/testdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority" where jj-test is your username who has write access, jj the password (although I'd make this longer even in test, sometimes short passwords don't meet complexity requirements and fail), svr is running locally on port 8000, your database is called testdb (you'll have to change it)